# How to increase/decrease price label value with button?

Tags: ios, label, swift4.2

I have two labels. First one is `quantityLabel` and the second one is `priceLabel`. When I click to increase or decrease button `priceLabel` increase or decrease with `quantityLabel` value. (e.g. 1 quantity is $15,00 2 quantity is $30,00)

I tried below

```
var quantity = 1
var updateFoodPrice: Double? {
    didSet {
        foodPrice.text = "\(Double(quantity) * updateFoodPrice!)"
    }
}

@IBAction func addQuantity(_ sender: Any) {
    if quantity < 30 {
        quantity += 1
        foodQuantity.text = String(quantity)

    }

}

@IBAction func decreasedQuantity(_ sender: Any) {
    if quantity > 0 {
        quantity -= 1
        foodQuantity.text = String(quantity)
        foodPrice.text? *= "\(quantity)"
    }
}
```

**Edit: Added DetailVC with full code**
My datas come from MainVC table view selected cell to DetailVc
    class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var foodTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodSubTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var drinkPicker: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var foodQuantity: UILabel!


var drinkPickerView = UIPickerView()
var selectDrinkType: [String] = []
var detailFoodName = ""
var detailFoodPrice = 0.0

var searchFoods: [String]!
var priceFood: [Double]!

let foods = Food(name: ["Hamburger big mac",
                           "Patates",
                           "Whopper",
                           "Steakhouse"], price: [15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0])
let food: Food! = nil

var foodPriceCount = FoodPriceCount(quantity: 1, foodPrice: 15.0) {

    didSet {
        foodQuantity.text = "\(foodPriceCount.quantity)"
        foodPrice.text = "\(Double(foodPriceCount.quantity) * foodPriceCount.foodPrice)TL"

    }
  }

@IBAction func addQuantity(_ sender: Any) {
    if foodPriceCount.quantity < 30 {
        foodPriceCount.quantity += 1
    }
  }

@IBAction func decreasedQuantity(_ sender: Any) {
    if foodPriceCount.quantity > 0 {
        foodPriceCount.quantity -= 1
    }
    }
```

**viewDidLoad()**

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    foodQuantity.text = "1"

    searchFoods = foods.name
    priceFood = foods.price

    foodTitle.text = detailFoodName
    foodPrice.text = String(detailFoodPrice)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `addQuantity` method you don't update the price label and in the `decreaseQuantity` method you can't use the label's text (string) and do math with it.

I suggest using a struct, that holds both values. The benefit of using a struct is that is is immutable. So every time you update a property inside of it, it creates a new instance of the struct. That way we can use the `didSet` callback to update the labels every time there's a change.

#### Define a ViewModel struct

```
struct ViewModel {
    var quantity: Int
    var foodPrice: Double
}
```

#### Update the labels

```
var viewModel = ViewModel(quantity: 1, foodPrice: 10) {
    didSet {
        foodQuantityLabel.text = "\(viewModel.quantity)"
        foodPriceLabel.text = "\(Double(viewModel.quantity) * viewModel.foodPrice)"
    }
}

@IBAction func addQuantity(_ sender: Any) {
    if viewModel.quantity < 30 {
        viewModel.quantity += 1
    }
}

@IBAction func decreasedQuantity(_ sender: Any) {
    if viewModel.quantity > 0 {
        viewModel.quantity -= 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct and more sense. foodPriceLabel's value is not constant like foodPrice: 10 it is value coming from previous table view's cell value. So it changes dynamically. I need to put my foodPrice: UILabel to ViewModel(foodPrice: foodPriceLabel) @lukas-würzburger

Comment: @EmreDeğirmenci I've updated the `didSet` function to be more clear. In the ViewModel you only hold the data. In the `didSet` function you update the UI.

Comment: Your example useful but I did not change `foodPrice: 10` parameter with my dynamic prices from preview screen. `foodPrice: 10` is just counting with 10 * quantity. When I tap each cell of table view in MainVC my food name and price go to DetailVC. When price came to DetailVC I need to update this price with increase/decrease button. @LukasWürzburger

Comment: The price is always calculated when setting the label text: `foodPriceLabel.text = Double(viewModel.quantity) * viewModel.foodPrice`

Comment: prices coming from this model                                                                                      ```let foods = Food(name: ["Hamburger big mac",
                               "Patates",
                               "Whopper",
                               "Steakhouse"], price: [15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0])``` to `foodPriceLabel.text`. Your `ViewModel(foodPrice: 10)` keeping only one value. How can I count with different `price:[15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0]`. If `priceLabel.text = 15.0` or `20.0` or `30.0` etc. @lukas-würzburger

Comment: Just change the value of the viewModel. Like `viewModel.foodPrice = 123.0`

Comment: Why we are disagree still. You say same thing  `viewModel.foodPrice = 123.0`. This is not different from `foodPrice: 10`. Two are same thing. I say foodPriceLabel is changing with previous screen priceLabel. It is not constant value!

Comment: By `foodPrice: 10` i mean `ViewModel(quantity: 1, foodPrice: 10)` and it changes the initial value. `viewModel.foodPrice = 123.0` changes the value after initialization. But it may be better if you explain how you pass the data. You talk about a table view that is shown before you see the view with the quantity. So once you tap a table view cell you know the food price and can change the view model's value.

Comment: This is how I imaging the thing: https://github.com/lukaswuerzburger/accumulated-price-ios/blob/master/AccumulatedPrice.playground/Contents.swift

Comment: I just added some code. link is about my app screen I am working with some static datas it has not web service yet. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_mdJG79Txs